# c#: color[] to brush[]

Tags: c#, colors, brush

How can I convert color[] into brush[]? I have tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cor3_local.length; i++)
{
Brush cor_local = new SolidBrush(cor3_local[i]);
}
```

but the cor_local gets no value.

cor3_local is color[5].

Comment: FYI you are reassigning same `cor_local` variable in a loop. And this variable will not be visible outside of the loop. Also it's not clear what is `cor3_local` and what data this array/collection has

Comment: What does `xmlfile` have to do with the array of colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var brushes = cor3_local.Select(c => new SolidBrush(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I get the following error:

'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` because `Select` is an extension method for arrays defined in that namespace.